# At what point does a file upload take place during a form submit?

Tags: php, html, ajax, file-upload

At what point during an HTML form submission is a file uploaded to the temp directory on a server (specifically PHP)? I have a form which has a few fields and a file upload. I am processing this form via AJAX.

I am using a 3rd party plugin which uploads the file via AJAX (using iFrame/xhr). Once the file is uploaded, the user may submit the form. Technically this file input field is within the form. When I process via AJAX, I am serializing the data for the entire form (including the file input field) and sending off for processing.

What I am wondering is; should I clear the file input field programatically via JS before the submit to prevent the client/server from attempting the file upload again? Or based on the functionality, is the field ignored alltogether in an AJAX call?

Basically I am just trying to determine, if the user uploads a 3MB file which takes 10 seconds to upload, when they actually submit the form (which I am capturing via jQuery), even tho the file cannot actually be uploaded, will they have to wait another 10 seconds while the client sends the file.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: It uploads when you tell it to upload

Comment: @Daryl what defines me telling it to upload? It moves the file from a temporary location to a permanent directory when I tell it to, but at what point is it uploaded to the temp directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are submitting the form via AJAX, you control what gets sent to the server. If you use `$('form').serialize()`, the file contents will not be included in the serialized data, so no...you don't have to clear that field. Just make sure you're preventing the default form submission.

To prevent the default form submission, you should do something like this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // the rest of your form submission stuff,
    // including your AJAX call

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Yes, I am using `$('form').serialize()`. So even though the file input value is being sent to the server, I am returning false via AJAX, so the default is prevented. Should be good?

Comment: @Chris: I would also use `preventDefault()` on the submit event...like this: `$('form').on('submit', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); /* your AJAX call goes here */ });`.

Comment: Ok, I will add that as well.